# What is the correct sql syntax to delete?

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm making a simple board. I want to delete an article to connect in DB one access after the user has input password.

So, I made a method in a DAO class. This is the query part.

```
        sql.append("DELETE FROM article ");
        sql.append("WHERE ? = (SELECT pwd FROM article WHERE no = ?) and no = ?");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        pstmt.setString(1, pwd);
        pstmt.setInt(2, no);
        pstmt.setInt(3, no);
```

Someone told me it is incorrect syntax. But, it is working.

Is it incorrect syntax?

Comment: definitely this is not about pure SQL but how you can create query in `x` language. where `x` seems to be `Java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Is it incorrect syntax?

The *syntax* of the SQL DELETE statement looks valid.  There's nothing "incorrect" about the syntax, in terms of it being a valid SQL statement to prepare and execute.

---

However, it does look like the subquery is not necessary. I believe an equivalent result could be achieved without a subquery.  We would tend to write a simpler statement, without the subquery. But that doesn't make the syntax of your statement "incorrect".

What we don't see is the reasoning for including the subquery. Why wouldn't this statement achieve an equivalent result?

```
   DELETE FROM article WHERE pwd = ? AND no = ?
```

Most (all?) relational databases are going to throw an error if (when) the subquery returns more than one row.  (We don't see any guarantee that `no` is unique in the `article` table.)

If the value in the `pwd` column is NULL, then the equality comparison "`pwd = ?`" in the WHERE clause is going to evaluate to NULL. So it's not possible for this statement to delete a row that has a NULL value for `pwd`. (The statement would need to be modified to allow deletion of rows with NULL values for `pwd` column.)

We don't see any Java code that initializes `sql`. We're going to assume that there's a previous line that sets the contents of `sql` to a zero length string, or whitespace and/or valid SQL comment.  Why not just

```
  sql = "DELETE FROM article"
        + " WHERE pwd = ?"
        + " AND no = ?";
```

On a style note, when I'm dynamically generating a statement, appending additional SQL syntax to an existing string, I tend to include the whitespace at the *beginning* of the string I'm adding, not at the *end* of what I'm going to add to.

---

If the `pwd` column is a "password", we're assuming that what's being stored is a hashed value, and not plaintext.

And we're assuming that this block is within a "try/catch/finally" block.

We can have some quibbles with the code.

But as far as the ***syntax*** of the SQL **DELETE** statement, it looks valid to me.

Comment: Thx, spencer! I will try it.

At first, i thought the SQL. My friend told me it is not. She told me that i have to compare password in DB and that the user has input password. So, Her's code is executed SELECT statement to bring password in DB and if two password values are equal, it deletes the article in DB.
But, i want to execute without SELECT statement.
`no` is unique in the `article` table. 

1. after SELECT statment, DELETE statment
2. just DELETE statment

What is the best?

Comment: In terms of raw database performance/scalability, I'd choose just one DELETE statement. But, if there's some requirement to distinguish between "*row with no=? does not exist*" and "*row with no=? does exist but password doesn't match*", a DELETE statement isn't going to provide that kind of feedback. if the DELETE statement is successful, it returns the number of rows deleted. And the number of rows deleted can be zero; and the statement execution is still successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have unnecessary subqueries in your statement. Why don't you simplify your query:

```
sql.append("DELETE FROM article WHERE no = ?");
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
pstmt.setInt(1, no);
```